# geoIntersects order documents

Tags: mongodb

In a $geoIntersects query like this

`db.places.find({ loc :
      { $geoIntersects :
        { $geometry :
          { type : "Polygon" ,
            coordinates: [ [ [ 0 , 0 ] , [ 3 , 6 ] , [ 6 , 1 ] , [ 0 , 0 ] ] ]
    } } } } )`

Is there a way to order documents based on the distance from a point?

Comment: No. That's not a feature of $geoIntersects and doesn't really fit conceptually with intersection - perhaps you could intersect with results from a $geoNear query?